# Required regex to avoid requested value occurs multiple times in given array

Tags: php, regex, validation

I have array from request. I want to validate it. E.g. If I have array,

```
$array = ['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'red'];

$request = ['colour' => 'red'];
```

In above case it should through validation as request value presents multiple times in given array.

Comment: You don't need regex for this, just use `in_array()`.

Comment: I want to through validation error and also want to check is this key presents multiple times in this array not once.

Comment: See [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

Answer (score 1):

So according to your new specs and edited question:

```
<?php

$array = ['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'red'];

$request = ['colour' => 'red'];

// Error counter
$errors = 0;

// If request shows up in the array.. move to next block
if( in_array( $request['colour'], $array ) ){

  /* Check how many times this key value shows up,then assign to count 
     variable.
     In this example, $request['colour'] is red
     array_count_values($arr) returns an array 
        $array['red'=> 2,'yellow'=> 1,...], so 
     show me the **count** in this array at array_key position for "red", 
     being two.
    */
    $count = array_count_values( $array )[ $request['colour'] ];
    // if this count is more than 1, increment our error flag for use later
    if ($count > 1){
        $errors++;
        echo "Ut oh, this value shows up more than once in our array";
    }

}
```

or for simplicity:

```
$count = array_count_values( $array )[ $request['colour'] ];

if ($count > 1){ $errors++; }

echo $errors;
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for late but I added my comment in question tab. What actually I want.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want if I understand your quetion properly http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

```
$array = ['red','red','yellow','green'];
$arr = array_unique($array);
// $arr would now be ['red','yellow','green'];
```

if I misunderstood this will give you the count of appearances in an array
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Answer (score 0):

If you want the count of each item in the array you can use array_count_values.

This will return an array with key "red" and the value 2.

```
var_dump(array_count_values($arr));
```

If you only want "red" as the output you can use array_diff to sort out all values that is `1`.

```
$array = ['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'red'];

$counts = array_count_values($array);
$oneOrMore = array_diff($counts, [1]);

var_dump($oneOrMore);

//array(1) {
//   ["red"]=>int(2)
//}
```

https://3v4l.org/FNYLS